# Netbeans - *Easy* way to tell which Netbeans project a file belongs to

Tags: netbeans, netbeans6.8, netbeans-plugins

I was wondering if there is a way in Netbeans (v 6.8, or whatever) to have the editor tabs colored based on which project the file belongs to?  Or some other *easy* way to distinguish which project a file belongs to.

Basically my problem is that I have 3-4 netbeans projects, which all have a *very* similar code base (production version, staging version, development version 1, development version 2), and sometimes I have files open from a few different projects, and I get confused as to which project the file belongs to.

And I know that you can hover over the tab and you can see which project it belongs to, but it would be fantastic if there was another, easier way to visually distinguish which project a file belongs to.

Comment: Never thought about it but it would be a great feature! +1.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

IN Netbeans 7.4 (may be some versions earlier too) you can actually set exactly what you have asked for.

Just look at the screenshot below.

[image: Netbeans 7.4 colored tabs grouped by project type]

**UPDATE:-** If you dont find these settings in the misceleneous tab try the appearence tab, seems like this has been moved recently. (16-08-2014)

Comment: Great, must be new in 7.4

Answer (score 4):

Update to 9kSoft answer. now (8.0.2) this option is in:
Tools->Options->Appearance->Document Tabs

[image: Options tab 8.0]

Answer (score 1):

right click on the editor and select the menu item "select in > projects". the shortcut key is "Command + Shift + 1" in mac. in linux/windows I think it is "Ctrl + Shift + 1". this causes the file you are editing, to be selected in the projects view. I do it all the time I'm confused which file in which project I'm working on.

Comment: I have used this pretty often also, except I never used the keyboard shortcut, which I'll bet will be more convenient.  I was hoping there would be some way to visually distinguish without having to click around and do keyboard shortcuts. Geez I am lazy! I suppose this is the *best* answer for now.

Answer (score 0):

I just hover over the title of the tab and it shows me the full path of the file. Then I can tell what project it is from by the folder name.